# Detect if class has method that is suitable for structured binding

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts, structured-bindings

Is there a way to write type trait or concept, that can be used to detect if type has a method that can be used in structured binding with particular types? Suppose `Q` is class in question. I want to get a compile time `bool` constant that tells me if objects of type `Q` can be used like so:

```
Q q;

auto [x1, x2] = q.method();
```

where `x1`, `x2` are `float`, and `bool` respectively.

Comment: From [structured_binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding), there is 3 cases, array, tuple-like types, and binding to data members. All cases are manageable ([magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get) handles the last).

Comment: some non-standard (gnu) can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340829/how-to-write-a-concept-for-structured-bindings